# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locals')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension, today when I tried to run the google chrome extension, shows error like this in `popup.js`:

```
popup.js:21888 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locals')
    at Object../node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/message.css (popup.js:21888:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:20:30)
    at Module../src/js/popup/index.js (popup.js:38789:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:20:30)
    at popup.js:84:18
    at popup.js:87:10
```

the npm build was success, but failed in the runtime,  I have no idea where is going wrong. this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "cruise-radar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Browser extension to detect available RSS and RSSHub for current page",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack -w --mode=development --progress --display-error-details --colors",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development --progress --display-error-details --colors",
    "release": "npm run build && zip -r release/radar.zip dist",
    "format": "eslint \"**/*.js\" --fix && prettier \"**/*.{js,scss,less}\" --write",
    "format:staged": "eslint \"**/*.js\" --fix && pretty-quick --staged --verbose --pattern \"**/*.{js,scss,less}\"",
    "format:check": "eslint \"**/*.js\" && prettier-check \"**/*.{js,scss,less}\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/Cruise-Radar.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rsshub",
    "rss"
  ],
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "npm run format:staged"
  },
  "author": "DIYgod",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/DIYgod/RSSHub-Radar/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/DIYgod/RSSHub-Radar#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.1",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "3.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-component": "1.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.3.0",
    "css-loader": "5.0.1",
    "cssnano": "4.1.10",
    "eslint": "7.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.15.0",
    "eslint-loader": "4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.4",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "js-wheel": "jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel",
    "less": "3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "7.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "prettier-check": "2.0.0",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10",
    "svg-inline-loader": "0.8.2",
    "template-string-optimize-loader": "3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "vue": "2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.12",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
    "yorkie": "2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.2",
    "clipboard": "2.0.6",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "element-ui": "2.14.0",
    "md5.js": "^1.3.5",
    "psl": "1.8.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "route-recognizer": "0.3.4",
    "rss-parser": "3.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.44.0",
    "vue-router": "3.4.9",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  }
}
```

and this is the project webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {

    mode: 'production',

    bail: true,

    devtool: false,

    performance: {
        maxEntrypointSize: 1000000,
    },

    entry: {
        'popup': './src/js/popup/index.js',
        'content': './src/js/content/index.js',
        'background': './src/js/background/index.js',
        'options': './src/js/options/index.js',
        'sandbox': './src/js/sandbox/index.js',
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.less'],
    },

    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/js'),
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    'template-string-optimize-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                            plugins: [
                                [
                                    "component",
                                    {
                                        "libraryName": "element-ui",
                                        "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
                                    },
                                ],
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                path: path.join(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js')
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                path: path.join(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js')
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'less-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                path: path.join(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js')
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    'limit': 40000
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                },
            },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css'
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: 'src/assets',
                    to: '',
                },
            ],
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./src/assets/manifest.json').version)
        }),
    ],

    node: {
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
    },

};
```

what should I do to fix this problem? I tried to debbuging with breakpoint, but it did not going into the breakpoint when I using the extension, only show this error when I open the popup page(did not trigger the error again). If I tried to reproduce the error, I have to close the popup window and reopen it.

For hours search and tried to debugging, finally from the error message I guess that my mac book pro system language was en, but the element-ui did not support the en right now(the other computer language set zh works fine). I just did not know how to make the element-ui support the en in the google chrome extension popup page, I only using the Message from element ui like this in the `popup.js`:

```
import { Message } from 'element-ui';
```

and there is no Vue or other framework that could let me set the multi language support, there is only one js file in the context, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Do basic debugging: find the code that reads `locals` and then investigate what's wrong. You can also enable "pause on exceptions" in devtools Sources panel: https://puu.sh/IMN9c/aa2637f843.png

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by changing node version to 12.14.0.